# Using JQuery to edit Data attributes on specific DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I put in the alerts because the changes were not showing when I did inspect element. However, when I click on the object the first time it brings up the "data is now false" alert as if I had already clicked it once.

HTML:

```
<li class="media-thumb" data-select="false"><img src="IMG HERE"></li>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {


    $(".media-thumb").click(function() {
        if($(this).data("select") === "false") 
            {
                alert("data is now true")
                $(this).data("select", "true");


            }
        else
            {
                alert("data is now false")
                $(this).data("select", "false");

            }
    });

});
```

Comment: why use `===` and not `==` ?

Comment: in the selector `$(".media-thumb")` do you mean `$(".image-thumb")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data-select` attribute is being returned as boolean `false` (per the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5): "Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value"), not a string.

So you can actually write:

```
$(".media-thumb").click(function() {
    if(! $(this).data("select")) 
        {
            alert("data is now true")
            $(this).data("select", true);
        }
    else
        {
            alert("data is now false")
            $(this).data("select", false);
        }
});
```

Example CodePen: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/Bnvub